# Why leaflet loads map with gray areas?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

This is my code:

```
let marker;

        function initMap() {
            var options = {
                center: new L.LatLng(35.7077714, 51.2075715),
                zoom: 13
            };

            var osmUrl = 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {
                    maxZoom: 19
                });

            var mapLayer = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl);

            this.map = new L.Map('map', options).addLayer(mapLayer);
        }
        initMap();
        map.on('click', e => {
            if (!marker) {
                marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {
                    draggable: true
                })
                marker.addTo(map)
            } else {
                marker.setLatLng(e.latlng)
            }

            document.getElementById("latlngPicker").setAttribute("value", e.latlng.lat + "," + e.latlng.lng);
        });`
```

When I load it to my page, the map is shown as below:
[image]

As you can see the map doesn't load properly and I don't know where the problem is because this code on the other page has no issues.

I would be grateful if someone could solve my problem :)

Comment: You're applying a `border-radius` CSS rule to all the images in the page. Debug which CSS rules are affecting the tiles.

Comment: You’re calling L.TileLayer twice, passing the first as an option for the second